# Исчезает свежесозданный js'ом элемент

Tags: javascript

У меня есть несколько столбцов, пытаюсь добавить функцию добавления строк в каждый из столбцов отдельно. В итоге получается так, что создаваемый элемент появляется на экране на долю секунды и исчезает. В дом дереве тоже не появляется.

```js
function addnew(elem) {
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  newdiv.innerHTML = document.getElementById('newlinktpl').innerHTML;
  newdiv.classList.add('row')
  elem.parentElement.appendChild(newdiv);
  alert(newdiv.className);
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="">

  <div class="yesterday">
    <a href="" onclick="addnew(this)" class="addnew">More links</a>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="Enter link">
        <p>Link</p>
        <input type="text" name="linkurl[]">
      </div>
      <div class="Enter HTML code of the page">
        <p>HTML code</p>
        <input type="text" name="linkcode[]">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="today">
    <a href="" onclick="addnew(this)" class="addnew">More links</a>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="Enter link">
        <p>Link</p>
        <input type="text" name="linkurl[]">
      </div>
      <div class="Enter HTML code of the page">
        <p>HTML code</p>
        <input type="text" name="linkcode[]">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <p>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit1">
    <input type="reset" name="reset1">
  </p>
</form>
<!-- Template -->
<div id="newlinktpl" style="display:none">
  <div class="Enter link">
    <p>Link</p>
    <input type="text" name="linkurl[]">
  </div>
  <div class="Enter HTML code of the page">
    <p>HTML code</p>
    <input type="text" name="linkcode[]">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Поскольку магии нет, значит у вас есть код который его удаляет. Нужен весь код или ссылка на живой пример

Comment: @alexey-ten добавил всю страницу. Стили сейчас пустые, там ничего испортить мне жизнь не может

Comment: Хм, так у вас видимо срабатывает переход по ссылке, т.к. я не вижу что бы вы его отменяли.

Comment: Да, именно это и было. Спасибо